# Remove duplicate user info from the flag history page

Tags: feature-request, design, flags, flag-history

**Important**

> My request is about page view for a **regular user**, not for a moderator.

---

On the [flag history page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current) (you can open it via “your profile - impact - helpful flags”) user info such as avatar, rep and badges is duplicated.

> [image: rep and badges]

All this info is already available in the top bar. I don’t see any reason to show it twice on the page. Could it please be removed?

There's already a code on that page that compares current user id with user id on requested page to printing out different phrases:

- Your flagging history
- Flagging history for $user$

Hence, the solution is easy - just move user card code into mod only branch where "Flagging history for $user$" is specified.

Answer (score 9):

This should not change, or if it does, it shouldn't change the moderator view of the page.

While regular users can't see other people's flag history, moderators can. Having this visible on the page is the only way mods can see this info for the person whose page they're viewing. Otherwise, we only have the text of their name.

I think having the user's info there is helpful.

---

Besides that, there are lots of user-specific pages that duplicate this information, so you'd also be asking them to remove it from your profile page, for example.

I don't really think there's a problem with information being duplicated, particularly when it's permanently affixed to the site design.

Comment: I didn’t know about mod page, in this case it could be helpful of course. But for regular user duplicating here is not necessary. All other cases of info duplication will be considered separately.