# Inconsistency in deleted questions/answers descriptions when looking at others' lists as a moderator

Tags: bug, profile-page, moderator-tools, wording, deleted-posts-pages

There appears to be a small bug in the text displayed at the top of the page when viewing `/users/deleted-answers/####` and `/users/deleted-questions/####`.

When following up on a flag at `/users/deleted-questions/####`, I came across this:

[image]

This is fine and all to see a helpful list of questions or answers when it happens to be helpful to have a peek here as a mod, except these are not *my questions* as this message  would appear to indicate.  Perhaps it is nitpicky, but consistency is nice :)

Even simply changing

> *This page shows questions **you asked** that were deleted.*

to something more like

> *This page shows questions **this user** asked that were deleted.*

would make a bit more sense.

Is this feasible or am I missing something?

Comment: Since only mods have access to this page other than the user themselves, "you asked" makes a lot more sense because most of the time, the user themselves will be the one looking at the page. Mods don't need that page to see deleted answers, they're all visible in the answer list directly.

Comment: @Catija ok that's fair. I only found it by following up on a flag anyway, and it didn't occur to me that it wasn't 10k but mod only.

Comment: Also: grammatical mistakes/faulty phrases are not bugs!

Comment: @Catija I would argue, because [flags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current) contains different wording for mods and current user. Despite existing a mod/user handling on that page my [related FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301146/339911) has been significantly downvoted.